# Python join all combinations of elements within each list

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples each with two elements: `[('1','11'),('2','22'),('3','33'),...n]`

How would I find all the combinations of each tuple with only selecting one element of the tuple at a time?

The example results:

> > [[1,2,3],[11,2,3],[11,2,3],[11,22,33],[11,2,33],[11,22,3],[1,22,3],[1,22,33],[1,2,33]]`

itertools.combinations gives me all combinations but does not preserve selecting only one element from each tuple.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [itertools.product](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
In [88]: import itertools as it
In [89]: list(it.product(('1','11'),('2','22'),('3','33')))
Out[89]: 
[('1', '2', '3'),
 ('1', '2', '33'),
 ('1', '22', '3'),
 ('1', '22', '33'),
 ('11', '2', '3'),
 ('11', '2', '33'),
 ('11', '22', '3'),
 ('11', '22', '33')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the `itertools` [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html)?

```
>>> import itertools
>>> l = [('1','11'),('2','22'),('3','33')]
>>> list(itertools.product(*l))
[('1', '2', '3'), ('1', '2', '33'), ('1', '22', '3'), ('1', '22', '33'), ('11', '2', '3'), ('11', '2', '33'), ('11', '22', '3'), ('11', '22', '33')]
```